# R: merging two data frames such that when there are duplicates, one dataset passes on the information

Tags: r, machine-learning, duplicates, regression, subset

I used a data.frame `trind` to train a machine learning regression that made predictions `pred`. `pred` is 100 times larger than `trind`, but there are *overlaps between the two*.

I would like to replace the prediction ratings with the training ratings from the `trind` to make `test` which I will see how it performs against a benchmark. I currently accomplish this with the help of `subset`, but it is a large bulky code. Does anyone have a more concise way?

```
trind <- data.frame(c(1,3,5), c(4,3,4))
names(trind) <- c("ID", "Rating")
pred <- data.frame(1:5, c(1,2,3,4,5))
names(pred) <- c("ID", "Rating")
temp <- subset(pred, pred$ID %in% trind$ID)
temp$Rating <- trind$Rating
temp2 <- subset(pred,! pred$ID %in% trind$ID)
test <- rbind(temp, temp2)
```

Comment: Are all `ID`s of `trind` also present in `pred`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general solution. First, create a data frame by combining `trind` and `pred`.

```
test <- rbind(trind, pred)
```

Second, remove the rows associated with duplicated `ID`s.

```
test <- test[!duplicated(test$ID), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? Assuming you have `pred` and `trind` already:

```
pred[ pred$ID %in% trind$ID, "Rating" ] <- trind$Rating
```